# Simple scroll button position doesn't listen me

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I'm creating html template with bootstrap, I have trouble with this button. I need to put it in bottom of picture. I think I'm doing correct way, but it doesn't work.

How should I fix it? And how to make it fixed in same position when I changing screen resoliution (responsive) :)

I know that my picture doesn't take whole height or something. It takes only col-xs-12 height, and when i want to create content after it displays same like button, in the middle of picture.

HTML:

```
<div class="container intro slider">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/as_royal-3final.jpg" alt="sliderimage">
      <div class="col-xs-12 slider">
        <h1 class="row sliderh1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, tempore</h1>
        <p class="row sliderp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <a href="#about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></a>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.intro -->
```

CSS:

```
.intro {
  background-size: cover;
}

.img-responsive {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.row.sliderh1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20%;
  color: #FFF;
}

.row.sliderp {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-down {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin: auto;
  color:#eee;
  bottom: 10px;

}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-down:active,
.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-down:hover,
.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-down:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
}
```

[image: And the photo for example with my troube:]

fiddle : 
[https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17670/)

Comment: Now u can check my fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the button at the bottom of the screen then you have to place your button outside the div.

**Updated Css**

```
.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-down {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin: auto;
  color:red;
  top: auto;//add this extra
  bottom: 10px;    
}
```

**Updated HTML**

```
<div class="container intro slider">
  <div class="black">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 slider">
    <h1 class="row sliderh1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, tempore</h1>
    <p class="row sliderp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>        
  </div>

</div><!-- /.intro -->
<a href="#about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down">button</span></a>
```

Put the a tag outside from the div.

Comment: Yes, it's working, but how should I fix second problem: I know that my picture doesn't take whole height or something. It takes only col-xs-12 height, and when i want to create content after it displays same like button, in the middle of picture. How I need to put it after picture?

Comment: If you want to show this after scroll some height then you have to use a jquery function named `scrollTop`

Comment: And the scroll button, is fixed on the bottom of whole page, I need to put it on the bottom of picture, thats why my a tag was inside container :)

Comment: is your container contain the full image??